# android listview update/refresh data without closing the app

Tags: android, mysql, facebook, sqlite, listview

I have an android application which fetches data from my web server and then display them on my listview and save to my local database (sqlite). If I add another record to my web server, the application should refresh/update my listview, just like the facebook app if there are new posts then display those posts.

this is what I have so far:

```
ListViewAdapter adapter;

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading Records");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array 
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given website URL in JSONfunctions.class
        String result = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL);

        try {
            JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
             {  
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                      jb = (JSONObject)jr.get(i);
                      map.put(TAG_ID, jb.getString(TAG_ID));
                      map.put(TAG_NAME, jb.getString(TAG_NAME));
                      arraylist.add(map);

                    String strID = jb.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    dbHelper.createEntry(strID);


             }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
} 

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
        //tv.setText("Successfully processed");

        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

fragments of my **listviewadapter.class**:

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView id;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    // Get the position from the results
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    resultp = data.get(position);

    // Locate the TextViews in list_item.xml
    id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listitem_id); 

    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    id.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.TAG_NAME));
    // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
    // Passes movie images URL into ImageLoader.class to download and cache
    // images
    // Capture button clicks on ListView items
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get the position from the results
            HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
            resultp = data.get(position);
            // Send single item click data to SingleMenuItemView Class
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            // Pass data 
            intent.putExtra("id", resultp.get(MainActivity.TAG_ID));
            intent.putExtra("name", resultp.get(MainActivity.TAG_NAME));
            // Start SingleItemView Class
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return itemView;
}
```

I also did add this:

```
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to no avail. It's not updating the list. It's just updating if I close the app and open it again. Any ideas how to do this? Help is pretty much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: again you need to call `DownloadJSON` **AsyncTask**.

Comment: When do you fetch the data? A simple way would be to periodically fetch the data using a background task and updated the list if there is new data..

Comment: @AmulyaKhare oh thank you I never thought of that, but my problem is how do I implement that periodic fetching?

Comment: @Tamilan where do I put DownloadJSON asynctask?

Comment: @Dunkey On button Click or where do you use refresh your adapter that time you have to call it.

Comment: @Dunkey ya sure try it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should schedule your `DownloadJSON` task to run periodically as follows:

```
public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        DownloadJSON performBackgroundTask = new DownloadJSON();
                        performBackgroundTask.execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10000); //execute in every 10 sec
}
```

This should work however its not the most efficient way as you are requesting the whole data again and again. (There is lots of data being downloaded which is not required).

Instead you should run a task periodically that checks the server if any **new updates** exist. If server says yes.. then it fetches the complete list.. otherwise it waits for some time and requests for new update again. But for this you need to modify the server API (so you can consider this in the future)

Comment: Well, I have a query to restrict rows that are already stored on my sqlite db. So do you think it's efficient enough?

Comment: I am not sure. This depends on your case. First make sure everything works as desired. Later you can do some measurements and see which way is more efficient..

Answer (score 1):

you can use Google Cloud Messaging(GCM) service in this case. Whenever any changes occur in your web server simply a push notification issued by this server will do for you. Catch it and  use it in your app accordingly. You can have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: Hi thanks, can you give me some sample implementations of GCM? If you don't mind dude.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ or http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139 and google :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need To set new  Adapter To listView ..

```
    newsAdapter = new NewsListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.custome_listview_news_item, newsItems);
        listViewNews.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
```

i assume that you have A fragment and you want to update the listview in fragment ..
So just make A method in Fragment To update The listview ..
And when you have new items ..   just request  this method within para your data ..
Note : you have to set new adapter ..

Comment: Hi thanks but this is just a simple app, I don't have a fragment