# How I can refres/update from server, in my ListView (CustomAdapter)

Tags: android, facebook, sqlite, android-listview, adapter

I have a question how to update a `ListView`, which uses a custom adapter, I try to do a `thread while (true).` Start() to always listen to the server (not work).

I want to update the list (status (offine, online ..), image, etc..). For example, in my `ListView`:

```
User 1 offine     
User 2, offine       
- Waiting, after 3 seconds     
User 1 online     
User 2, offline
```

I have read that this can be done with `handler`:

[android listview update/refresh data without closing the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323089/android-listview-update-refresh-data-without-closing-the-app)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030607/update-list-view-in-android

But there is a way to refresh the data from the server without handler?

I load list (how do I get always actualize?) :

```
listAdapter1 = getListData();
customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listAdapter1);
user_list.setAdapter(customListAdapter);
egisterForContextMenu(user_list);
```

My full log cat:

```
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver@4e9c7894 was not registered.
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.database.Observable.unregisterObserver(Observable.java:69)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.widget.BaseAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(BaseAdapter.java:42)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onDetachedFromWindow(AbsListView.java:2638)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:12160)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2570)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2568)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:2820)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5162)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:5145)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:359)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:309)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3535)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-17 22:46:07.439: E/AndroidRuntime(6026):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: how can you populate your getlistData? and what is the problem?please can you explain? I mean , when you update it what happens?

Comment: It is difficult to explain. why? because my method works and does not work, if I put on a Thread, tells me: "IllegalStateException. android.w Observer ... was not registered" but if I use a button, it works (but I do not want a button), it that I want is to work with the thread, I used "Thread with runnable", "executors" and tell me that ". android.w Observer ... was not registered", I mean that the threads do not record items inside, and do not know how to register.

Comment: Any idea about the problem ?

Comment: can you write full log cat , what means **.. was not registered**

Comment: I try register observer + handler into thread, when I worked all (Thread , register obserber + handler, + my method) call "IllegalStateException: Observer android... was not registered." always call this error .. pff

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to implement above functionality. See below points so you will get idea/logic of this.

- You need alarmmanager, broadcastreceiver & service for this.
- AlarmManager will help you to check for updates after every 3 seconds.
- BroadcastReceiver & Service will help to handle newly coming notification & updating UI.
- You need to use "notifyDataSetChanged()" method to show updated listview.

These 4 steps are enough to implement above logic. Still in case if you have any doubts you can discuss with me.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I've been busy, I save your answer